# Attempting to make a NES Zapper Lamp and need wiring help

Tags: lamp

So I have a Nintendo Zapper gun that broke and I want to turn it into a Desk lamp.  But I want to use the Trigger as the On/Off switch.  Can somebody please help me and point me in the right direction on how I would wire that? Anybody familiar with that?

Comment: How to wire a lamp through a switch? Seems like some basic research could answer that.

Comment: If you just like the look of the gun, your best bet would be to gut it- save the switch- and just buy a simple lamp wiring kit. However, you still need to determine safety factors and know the tolerances of the switch etc. I recommend lots of reading before you plug anything into mains.

Comment: This question should be nominated for most random question of the year.

Comment: Watch out for 120V

Comment: Thx guys, Im researching but haven't found anything that would help as well as find the tolerance on the switch on the zapper.  Im stating the obvious here but I know nothing about wiring and thought that with some research and how to maybe I can tackle it.  Upon researching I came across this site and figured Id ask the pros

Answer (score 2):

Nintendo Zapper gun use a push button switch also that button doesn't handle high voltage so you need a circuit for that.

This circuit is build around a relay and 555 timer configured in a way that let it latch on one state and an action is required to change state. The  circuit is powered from +5V

[image]
[image]

The project is [here](http://www.electronics-lab.com/project/toggle-on-off-switch/)